# Converting a string like "09335887170" to an integer

Tags: c#, .net

How can I convert a string like "09335887170" to an integer? Here is what I have tried:

```
string a = "09335887170";
int myInt;
bool isValid = int.TryParse(a, out myInt); // it returns false in this case

if (isValid)
{
    int plusOne = myInt + 1;
    MessageBox.Show(plusOne.ToString());
}

MessageBox.Show(a);
int stringToInt = Convert.ToInt32("09335887170"); // it returns nothing with no error
MessageBox.Show((stringToInt + 1).ToString());

int test = int.Parse(a); //it has type convertion error            
MessageBox.Show((test + 1).ToString());
```

Comment: that number is way too big for an integer. have you considered using a long?

Comment: Check out Long or a BigInteger. Also for getting details just use the "Parse"-method to get a clear exception.

Comment: 1. Use a normal `Parse` 2. Run code and get an error 3. Google the error message.... then you will have your solution, much easier then asking this question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The maximum value of a `Int32` (or only `int`) is 2,147,483,647
you need a `UInt64` or `Int64` or `Long`

```
string a = "09335887170";
Int64 myInt;
bool isValid = Int64.TryParse(a, out myInt);
if (isValid)
{
    int plusOne = myInt + 1;
    MessageBox.Show(plusOne.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Or just a "Long" which Int64 represents. ;)

Comment: This doesn't actually compile.  You should use `long` or `Int64`.

Comment: there is no `int64`, just `Int64` or `long`.

Comment: @trade yeah, I forgot to add this! I'll make an edit

Comment: @recur sorry, I forgot about the capital 'I'. I edited my code

Comment: int64 is not recognized in Visual-studio .net 4.5

Comment: And uint (UInt32) is not big enough.  I changed your answer to UInt64.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0sksh43.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
result = Convert.ToInt64(value);
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx/) for more info.

(Found online, im not really in c#)

Answer (score 1):

that number exceeds the max int value.  use a long instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Int64  no = Convert.ToInt64(  "09335887170");
```

Comment: use `Parse` not `Convert`